# merge search results of tables with different colums and sort by date

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, merge

I'm trying to build a search result of three differend log tables with one output. This output has to be sorted by "time" and echoed in a foreach loop.

1. table

   id | record-id | user_id | time | sector | info
2. table

   id | user_id | ip | time | path | info | message | level
3. table

   id | req_id | user | time | info | type | ip

The three results would all be different and hardly be comparable ...

The question is, where and how to merge the result ... I dont think I can handle this with only one query, or? JOIN (there is no reference) and UNION (different count of colums) may be the wrong choice?

If there is no other option I can make 3 querys and merge the result array like that

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a['time'] == $b['time']) {
    return 0;
  }

  return ($a['time'] < $b['time']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$new_arr = array_merge($result1, $result2, $result3);
uasort($new_arr, 'cmp');
```

Comment: It's not possible to do in sql

Comment: What is the format of your `time` columns? Try converting them to an easy to manipulate format using `strtotime()` before you do any comparisons.

Comment: its datetime - but it seem to compare quiet well without the strtotime() are there other reasons to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `UNION ALL` and `CONCAT_WS()` to unify your resultset into fixed number of columns (5 in an example below). And then `explode()` `details` column values in php while you iterate over your resultset.

```sql
SELECT 1 source, id, record_id id2, time, CONCAT_WS('|', user_id, sector, info) details
  FROM table1
 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, id, user_id, time, CONCAT_WS('|', ip, path, info, message, level)
  FROM table2
 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, id, req_id, time, CONCAT_WS('|', user, info, type, ip)
  FROM table3
 ORDER BY time DESC, source, id, id2
```

Sample output:

```
| SOURCE | ID |  ID2 |                TIME |                                                              DETAILS |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 | 11 |  111 | 2013-06-30 16:00:00 |                                              12|sector1|info details |
|      2 | 12 |   13 | 2013-06-30 15:00:00 | 10.10.10.1|/your/path/some/where|info details|message details|level1 |
|      3 | 13 | 1024 | 2013-06-30 12:00:00 |                              user1|info details|type info|10.10.10.2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73894/4)** dmeo

Comment: a really nice approach ... Dont know if I will use this for my actual task, but I would consider to use it for other things because its a really comprehensible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a union as long as you "stretch" the results of the unbalanced columns, e.g.

```
SELECT 'table1' AS source, record_id, user_id, time, sector, path
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2', user_id, null, null, ip, etc....
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table3', null, req_id, null, null, ip, etc...
```

Basically for any field that's common between the three table, or at least type-compatible, you can use a particular column in the results for that field. For unmatched/type-imcompatible fields in one table, simply select `NULL`  as the 'matching' value in the other queries.

However, this makes your client-side logic far more complicated, so you're probably better off just biting the bullet and running 3 different queries. At some point, the minor efficiency gains of firing off a single union'd query are outweighed by the extra processing you have to do in the client to separate out the relevant data again.

Comment: thats really correct... obviously its the goal to always reduce the querys but you have to care about the costs. And this will be a function for an admin, little used.